# Python Euler Practice

Tags: python

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Finish the solution so that it returns the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below the number passed in.

Note: If the number is a multiple of both 3 and 5, only count it once. Also, if a number is negative, return 0(for languages that do have them)

```
def solution(number):
    sum = 0
    if(number <= 0):
        return 0
    else:
        for i in range(1,number+1):
            if( i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0 and i % 15 != 0 ):
                sum += i
    return sum
```

There are 105 test cases for this challenge in codewars, 55 of them passes and 50 of them don't. How can I improve my code?

p.s : I do not see which cases pass or which are do not.

p.s 2 : GUYS NOTHING CHANGES WHEN I REMOVE **i % 15 != 0**

Comment: Include a few test cases that work, and some that fail. Include inputs, expected outputs and actual results. While this is very simple code, it will make the question overall better.

Comment: why are you ruling out multiples of 15? That will be where the error is. The description only cautions you not to count them twice, which some badly-thought-out implemetations might do - but yours won't.

Comment: According to the example, you shouldn't count the input. Change to `for i in range(1, number):`

Comment: Not related to the error, but it's not the best of ideas to overwrite the builtin [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). You might want to use an other name like `total`.

Comment: The answer is you don't need to use a for loop here. You should be doing 3 partial sums here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omit the last test (`i % 15 != 0`), the condition becomes `i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0`, which is what the question is asking for, also, the question says `below` the number passed in, so exclude `number` from the `range`:

```
def solution(number):
    sum = 0
    if number <= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        for i in range(1, number):
            if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
                sum += i
    return sum
```

Comment: Actually nothing changed in test section :/

Comment: @apotamkinn the question says `below` the number passed in, so I think you should use `range(1, number)`, which is why they didn't include `10` in their example, even though it's a multiple of `5`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't counting multiples of 15? I might be wrong but it looks like you say saying if i is divisible by (3 or 5) but not 15 then it counts.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the **i % 15 != 0** condition, it is never tested because the previous conditions are already satisfied, also  range should be range(1,number), because the request was **below the number passed in** (e.g. 21 and 22 should give the same answer)

```
def solution(number):
    sum = 0
    if(number <= 0):
        return 0
    else:
        for i in range(1,number):
            if( i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0 ):
                sum += i
    return sum  

print(solution(21))
print(solution(22))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could improve your code by defining a function to filter values using [lambda notation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) and passing it to the `filter` function. You can then use the inbuilt `sum` to get your result.

```py
def solution(number):
    is_multiple_of_3_5 = lambda x: x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0
    return sum(filter(is_mult_of_3_5, range(number)))
```

In my opinion, this is cleaner and easier to read than loops but this is just a  preference.

It is slightly slower, however. So, here's a third option using a generator expression that keeps the speed but is more concise.

```py
def solution(number):
    return sum((x for x in range(number) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0))
```

Running for number 1000000:

Original Code:
82.5 ms ± 1.93 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Using lambda and filter:
104 ms ± 583 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Using generator expression:
81.3 ms ± 895 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Python syntax, but the idea here is you should not be using a for loop here.

If my guess is correct, some of the test cases are intentionally arbitrarily large, with a for loop, it will likely timeout on your site.

Instead, you should be thinking the question like `(3+6+9+...+3j)+(5+10+15+...+5k)-(15+30+45+...+15m)`:

```
def solution(number):
    number -= 1
    a1 = number - number % 3
    a2 = number // 3
    b1 = number - number % 5
    b2 = number // 5
    c1 = number - number % 15
    c2 = number // 15
    return (3 + a1) * a2 // 2 + (5 + b1) * b2 // 2 - (15 + c1) * c2 // 15
```